# How to describe that inputs types are equal and of a limited set of possible types in flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Consider a basic sort function that should work with strings or numbers (or some future things like dates).

```
function baseSorter<T>(lval: ?T, rval: ?T): -1|0|1 {
    if (lval === rval) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (lval === null || lval === undefined) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (rval === null || rval === undefined) {
        return -1;
    }
    return lval > rval ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Flow will complain about this that T cannot be compared to T. Which is logical as `T` might be something complex that doesn't provide comparison. So I tried to reduce the type:

```
function baseSorter<T: number|string>(lval: ?T, rval: ?T)
```

However now flow errors on that `number` cannot be compared to a `string`. However since I have to pick one type on function call it should be able to deduce that both sides are equal type?

Answer (score 0):

`<T: number|string>(lval: ?T, rval: ?T)` Doesn't actually mean that `lval` and `rval` have to be the same. It's saying that `lval` and `rval` have to satisfy type T, which can be a `number` or `string`.

For example, here's a few use cases

```
baseSorter('123', 123) // works
baseSorter(123, 123) // works
baseSorter(123, true) // fails because boolean does not satisfy T requirements
```

Think of T as a type (number) or literal (the number `1`). And when you do `(lval: ?T, rval: ?T)`, you're saying that `lval` and `rval` are matching the same type, which in your case is a union `string | number`.

So to ensure your function is sound you'll need something like this try-flow
https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAoglsAFhATlAvFAzsFcB2A5lAD5T4CuAtgEaoDcAUIwGYX4DGwcA9vlDQCGWCAGUeKYKgA8AFQBcsBMhQA+ABQAbAG6DNigPyyANFBS79UIwEpFAWgCMJAAwkHUAN6MoPqHBZQWhYY6Jjmetae3r4xKBDAFCj8zkwxAL7RPv6BOnohmJSamqRkucWhmOwAJhAsBBBVkV4xsfGJ-A6pvhkx2erh5aHkFEUlZsEVUNW19Y1RLb5xCUlQjl0+Pb59oJA8AWX5UADkOHhER1AAZJdQOxB743mTJ7gEhEdNmYttKweqj8UDFB3PZOl9NlkAuo7g8Ds9KLRUBdrrdwPcAgNDkcEXQUB95i0lu0oH8AVZgVBQesoJsiSs1owMowhCJxJJUOoHAAmADMpheZ3e1iYLLEEikKHUAreR35pxlwuZwjF7Ml3L5wN5itFbIlnN5plwFAgisYQA

Comment: If that would be the case, then what's the point of having a generic in the first place? If the type for each "filling in" of the generic can be different there's no difference to `foo<T>(x: T, y: T)` and `foo<T, U>(x: T, y: U)` and practically there's no difference to `foo(x: mixed, y: mixed)`

Comment: Well I guess that really depends on your use case to determine how useful generics are to your problem. You can use them to define an object structure so that you don't get errors when you try to reference something, or to create boundaries so that callers don't call your function with the wrong parameters or to keep your args type in sync with what's returned. You're right that `foo<T>(x: T, y: T)` and `foo<T, U>(x: T, y: U)` are the same, and in your case `foo(x: mixed, y: mixed)` may be the same also because you're not taking advantage of generics in a meaningful way.

Comment: Well this leaves the original question then unanswered: "how do I describe that a function takes 2 parameters which can be of multiple types but need to be equal?"